# android, custom class with getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Im developing an app that uses a lot of network requests for data retrieval.
The network request is currently a `URLConnection`, with `HttpsURLConnection`.

Issue I've got is that i call `getApplicationContext()` a couple of times. This has been fine prior when i declare the class inside of the activity class, however i wish to just have the AsyncTask declared in a separate class, to be imported to activity classes where needed. I'm assuming that i cannot `getApplicationContext()` from the custom class as it is not extending the activity. How would i resolve this? Can i pass the context as a parameter when i instantiate it?

---

would something like this work:

```
Context contxt = getApplicationContext();
CustomClass custmClass = new CustomClass();
ArrayList<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
parameters.add(contxt);
...
custmClass.execute(parameters);
```

Where `CustomClass extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Object>, Void, Boolean>`?

Comment: Yes. pass context as a constructor params of AsyncTask class. `new MyTask(context).execute();`

Comment: Yes you can pass the context to the other class. Do some research about how to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i pass the context as a parameter when i instantiate it?

Yes. You can pass current `Context` as parameter to your custom class.

### 1st Way:

Create single Argument Constructor in your Custom Classs

```
Context myCon;

public myClass(Context mCon){
 this.myCon=mCon;
}
```

And you can access in your `Activity` like

```
myClass mc=new myClass(Activity.this);
```

### 2nd Way:

By passing to Custom class method directly

```
public void getCount(Context mCon){
 //Directly used mCon here
}
```

### Current Solution:

```
Context contxt = getApplicationContext();
CustomClass custmClass = new CustomClass(contxt);
ArrayList<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
parameters.add(contxt);
...
custmClass.execute(parameters);
```

Comment: What if user rotates the screen?

Comment: @Raghunandan In that case you have to pass main `Application Context` to `Custom class`. As per my aspect.

Comment: please see the edit in my question about potential possibility?

Comment: I believe the first way can lead to memory leaks. If you are keeping a reference to an activity that doesn't exist anymore. It won't be garbage collected. And as Raghunandan pointed out, device rotation can be problematic as it creates a new Activity.

Comment: @miva2 Then there is only one way out. You can used `Application Context`.

Comment: @MD weakreference is much better. Although there are others way of doing things..

Comment: @Raghunandan I know men. There are many solutions but OP doesn't clear this in question. so i provided this solution as per his question.

Answer (score 4):

As told in the other answers, you should pass the context as a parameter to your AsyncTask.
Still, you can got lots of problems doing this, if you close your activity for example while the AsyncTask is executing and using this reference this will cause an exception.

To prevent this, avoid having a strong reference to your activity as mentioned in the other posts and use weak references. Make sure you always check if the return value of your weak reference is null.

Example :

```
import com.example.MyActivity;

public class MyTask {

    private final WeakReference<MyActivity> myActivity;

    public MyTask(MyActivity myActivity) {
        this.myActivity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(myActivity);
    }

    private AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> createAsyncTask() {
        return new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // prepare execution
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
                // code
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                if (myActivity.get() != null && !myActivity.get().isFinishing()) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in one of your activities (the main activity is better) declare this

```
public static Context context;
```

in your oncreate add this

```
 context=getApplicationContext();
```

and in other classes just use

```
MainActivity.context
```

this works for me